# Complex Wiener process on Hilbert spaces

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, hilbert-spaces, brownian-motion, covariance

Does someone know if the theory of Q-Wiener processes in Hilbert spaces (like in the Book stochastic equations in infinite dimensions) also work for a complex Wiener process? For example can I represent a complex Q-Wiener process as an infinite sum with the help of the eigenvalues of Q?

Note that Q denotes the covariance operator of the Wiener process.

I am very grateful for every answer or some literature to this topic, since I am not finding anything to that.